# Transient dependencies with Gradle & Google Cast

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, google-play-services

I just updated my Android-app to buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" and wanted to also update the libraries required for Casting to Chromecast.

Those libraries are:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.8.0'
}
```

After testing a while with the versions (play-services-cast:8.1.0 introduces ProGuard-problems), I realized that I can also just this this dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.8.0'
}
```

So this means, that appcompat & mediarouter seem to be transient dependencies of play-services-cast.

Who can tell me what happens and what's the recommended way?

1. declare appcompat, mediarouter + play-services-cast as before because then the transient dependency is omitted?
2. just use play-services-cast and use its transient dependencies to appcompat & mediarouter?

What version of appcompat & mediarouter are used if I declare them by myself? Or are multiple versions used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please update your play services to 8.1.0; that is already out and has a number of improvements. Now back to your main question. You can get the tree of dependencies by running `gradle dependencies`. Let's assume we have a simple project that depends on cast, media router and appcompat. If I do not add the last two as dependencies, here is what the gradle reports for my dependency tree:

```
_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.1.+ -> 8.1.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
     |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0
     \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
          \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0
               \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 (*)
```

So as you can see, for my 8.1.0 version of cast play services, it is grabbing v22.2.0 of the support libs. Since that is actually available in my local repository (as part of my Android SDK), it finds that and I can compile my project without adding explicit appcompat and mediarouter dependencies. However, if I go to my local repository (e.g. in `<SDK_HOME>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7` and rename the `22.2.0` directory there that holds the v22.2.0 of media router and try to compile my project again, it fails.
Now if I add the dependencies on appcompat and mediarouter (v23.1) back into the build gradle, it finds those new libraries and uses those; here is the `gradle dependencies` tree:

```
_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.+ -> 23.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0
+--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.1.+ -> 23.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.1.+ -> 8.1.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.1.0 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.1.0 (*)
```

which is a good news; so to answer your question, include your up-to-date version of dependencies since they fix old bugs and have newer features in them.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much Ali for the detailed feedback!